# maxIter parameter in spark ml.classification

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

What is the role of the `maxIter` parameter used in LogisticRegression from `pyspark.ml.classification`?.

```
mlor = LogisticRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, weightCol="weight",
     family="multinomial")
```

Answer (score 5):

Logistic regression is optimized by iterative methods like gradient descent. It is most likely the maximum number of iterations to run the optimization algorithm.